# Konga set JWT plugin

Tags: java, kong

Currently, I am using Konga as our gateway, however, I have meet a problem that  is about token. I am config the jwt plugin for a service and a route, and then I request the original url. It is always going wrong. like Authorization denied. Could some one tell how I can config the server with jwt and the token valid within 2 hours.

Comment: This sounds like a support issue

Comment: When I request the url, it gives back "No credentials found for given 'iss'". Possiblely, I config something wrong. could you help me out

Comment: Finally, It is resolved. The reason why I had the problem was that many of my colleagues logined in our platform system and the token had refreshed frequently. So that was the problem. Thx

Comment: You can answer your own question (and accept it) so that its 1. clear that its solved and 2. makes it so anyone else searching their way here have a clear answer :)